# How to delete File in strapi via api

Tags: strapi

Trying to delete image in upload folder.

```
axios.delete(`${backendUrl}/uploads/files/${id}`})
```

The code above returns an error

`DELETE http://localhost:1337/api/uploads/71 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

Can anybody help to understand how to delete upload properly?

Comment: Are you sure your endpoint is allowing these methods with the user you are trying ?

Comment: Well, there's no delete method in default strapi routes, but there is destroy which is enabled.